# Why my cookie doesn't write down a value into input(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I make cookie wishing write down the value of that into an input. I succeed in making cookie but i can't perform second step. What's problem? Please, explain my mistake to let me know how to handle with it in the future! Thanks.

```js
 var init = function () {
 var time = new Date();
 time.setMonth(time.getMonth() +1);
 var cookieVal = document.getElementById("first").value;
 document.cookie = "first" + "=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" + time.toGMTString();
 valArray = document.cookie.split(";");
 return valArray[1];
}
 document.getElementById("done").onclick = init;
 document.getElementById('first').value = init();
```

```html
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="button" id="done" value="Готово!">
  </form>
```

Comment: what should be the initial value in the cookie ? you are accessing value of textbox "first" which does not have value in the initial case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like (as it's written) it's going and getting the `done` button and the `first` textbox before the page is loaded.

By reorganizing the code to use proper event handling, this code works:

```js
var txtFirst = null, btnDone = null;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

     txtFirst = document.getElementById("first");
     btnDone = document.getElementById("done");
  
     btnDone.addEventListener("click", init);

});


function init() {

 var time = new Date();    
 time.setMonth(time.getMonth() +1);
 var cookieVal = txtFirst.value;
  
 document.cookie = "first=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" + time.toGMTString();
  
 valArray = document.cookie.split(";");
 txtFirst.value = valArray[1];
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="button" id="done" value="Готово!">
</form>
```

Of course, having the user type their name in the same box that you want to put their name into may seem like it doesn't work, so I think you want something like this:

```js
var txtFirst = null, btnDone = null;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

     txtFirst = document.getElementById("first");
     btnDone = document.getElementById("done");
  
     btnDone.addEventListener("click", setCookie);
  
     if(document.cookie){
       getCookie();
     }

});


function setCookie() {

 var time = new Date();    
 time.setMonth(time.getMonth() +1);
 var cookieVal = txtFirst.value;
 document.cookie = "first=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" + time.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie() {
 txtFirst.value = document.cookie.split(";")[1];
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="button" id="done" value="Готово!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a couple mistakes in your code:

1. When you start the page you call `init()`, your input is empty but you're saving it's emptiness into your cookie, deleting the previous value
2. I'm not sure why you're using `valArray[1]`, if you're trying to retrieve the first value it should be: `valArray[0]`

I recommend you to have two separate functions, one for setting your cookie and the other one to retrieve that value:

```js
var setvalue = function() {
    var time = new Date();
    time.setMonth(time.getMonth() +1);
    var cookieVal = document.getElementById("first").value;
    document.cookie = "first" + "=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" + time.toGMTString();
}
var getvalue = function() {
    valArray = document.cookie.split(";");
    return valArray[0];
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("done").onclick = setvalue;
    document.getElementById('first').value = getvalue();
})
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="button" id="done" value="Готово!">
  </form>
```